# How do I see the transaction amounts, sum of total amount for a particular account number in the Hedera_etl on Big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to Query the Hedera-ETL public dataset :
So far I have this but it doesn't return any results: SELECT h.amount FROM `hedera-etl.mainnet.transactions`,unnest(transactionRecord.transferList.accountAmounts) as h where  transaction.body.nodeAccountID.accountNum = 27500
The following is the schema:
[schema of hedera-etl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qObTL.png)

Answer (score 0):

it just mean that there is no `accountNum = 27500`- do you think this is a case? as of query - it looks totally correct to me!

to prove this  - try below

```
SELECT h.amount 
FROM `hedera-etl.mainnet.transactions`,
unnest(transactionRecord.transferList.accountAmounts) as h 
where transaction.body.nodeAccountID.accountNum = 3
```

with output quite an output - 810,535,513 rows

[image]

Comment: Hey man, firstly I can't thank you enough for replying, secondly there defo has to be an account with that ID https://app.dragonglass.me/hedera/accounts/0.0.27500:

Comment: i though above proves that there is no `accountNum = 27500` ! meantime, I see few other `accountNum` fields in the schema - you might be using wrong one? just a guess